Node-red split data from serial input
I'm trying to read data into two different gauss in Node-RED.
I have these flow:

In the function block I have these code:
var lines = msg.payload.split('\r\n');
var adcValue = parseFloat(lines[0].split(':')[1]);
var temperature = parseFloat(lines[1].split(':')[1]);

msg.payload = adcValue, temperature;
return msg;


These are provenient from the code below, who is flashed on my STM32.
if(converADC == 1){
              rawValueconta = rawValue;
              converADC = 0;
              HAL_ADC_Stop_IT(&hadc3);
            while(counter < 10000){
              if(flag == 1){
                  flag = 0;
              sprintf(msg, "ADC rawValue: %hu\r\n", rawValueconta);
              HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, (uint8_t*) msg, strlen(msg), 100);
              temp = ((float)(110-30)/ (float)(*(TS_CAL2)-*(TS_CAL1)))*(float)(rawValueconta-*(TS_CAL1))+(float)30;
              sprintf(msg, "Temperature: %.2f\r\n", temp);
              HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, (uint8_t*) msg, strlen(msg), 100);
              HAL_ADC_Start_IT(&hadc3);
                 if(converADC == 1){
                 rawValueconta = rawValue;
              }
    }
    }
    }
    }
      converADC = 0;

I want to get the temperature value in one gauss and the adcValue into another one.
How can I do it?
Thank you

First, what is the format of your msg? You have a debug node, what the debug node show?

Without seeing an example of the input we really can't help here.
